Script getting stuck in while trying to continuously read from a pipe in a while loop
I am trying to implement a script in which a pipe is getting created and the default value 0 is stored in the pipe. Simultaneously, a c code file is getting executed which based on a condition updates the value in pipe to 1.
In the script, the pipe value is being read continuously, based on which if the pipe value is updated then another variable's flag value will be changed to 1 and the loop will end. But the problem is that read takes a lot time to read due to which the script is getting stuck inspite of using the timeout feature.
#!/bin/bash

pipe_name="/tmp/my_pipe"
initial_value="0"

# Create the named pipe if it does not exist
if [ ! -p "$pipe_name" ]; then
    mkfifo "$pipe_name"
fi

# Function to initialize the pipe with the initial value
initialize_pipe() {
    echo "$initial_value" > "$pipe_name" &
}

# Initialize the pipe
initialize_pipe

STOP_FH_LOGS="$initial_value"

while true; do
    # Using read with a timeout to avoid blocking indefinitely
    if read -t 1 new_value < "$pipe_name"; then
        STOP_FH_LOGS=$new_value
        
        # Check the read value and write it back to the pipe
        if [ "$STOP_FH_LOGS" = "0" ]; then
            echo "$STOP_FH_LOGS" > "$pipe_name" &
            echo "Condition still 0"
        elif [ "$STOP_FH_LOGS" = "1" ]; then
            echo "Value changed to 1"
            break
        else
            echo "New STOP_FH_LOGS error value: $STOP_FH_LOGS"
            # Optionally, write back the new value if needed
            echo "$STOP_FH_LOGS" > "$pipe_name" &
        fi
    else
        # Handle timeout or no data read scenario
        echo "Timeout or no data read"
        # Ensure the pipe is not empty
        if [ ! -p "$pipe_name" ]; then
            initialize_pipe
        fi
    fi
done


A sample c code trying to change the code in the pipe is as follows:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PIPE_NAME "/tmp/my_pipe"
#define INITIAL_VALUE "0"
#define NEW_VALUE "1"

void write_to_pipe(const char *value) {
    int pipe_fd = open(PIPE_NAME, O_WRONLY);
    if (pipe_fd == -1) {
        perror("Failed to open pipe for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (write(pipe_fd, value, strlen(value)) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to write to pipe");
        close(pipe_fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(pipe_fd);
}

int main() {
    char buffer[2];
    int pipe_fd;

    while (1) {
        pipe_fd = open(PIPE_NAME, O_RDONLY);
        if (pipe_fd == -1) {
            perror("Failed to open pipe for reading");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        ssize_t num_read = read(pipe_fd, buffer, 1);
        if (num_read == -1) {
            perror("Pipe read error");
            close(pipe_fd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        buffer[num_read] = '\0';
        close(pipe_fd);

        // Check if the current value is "0"
        if (strcmp(buffer, "0") == 0) {
            write_to_pipe(NEW_VALUE);
            break;
        }

        sleep(1); // Sleep to avoid busy-waiting
    }

    return 0;
}


Tried the timeout condition but it is still getting stuck, so need suggestions as to what can be done

How is it not working ? tried with another shell echo 1 > /tmp/my_pipe and Value changed to 1, the timeout is not triggered because the script continously writes 0 to the pipe

Add set -x to the top of your shell script so you can see what it's doing. I can't make sense of it (it appears to be reading a line from a pipe then, if it's not 1, writing that same line back to the same pipe in an infinite loop while a separate C program is apparently also writing to that same pipe?) so it may not be doing what you intended it to.

#define NEW_VALUE "1" and write(pipe_fd, value, strlen(value) You do not write a newline from your C code.
Shell read waits for a newline, so it's stuck waiting for a newline.

what can be done

You can write and read newline from the pipe just like you do in bash, like:
#define NEW_VALUE "1\n"

And something along:
    char c;
    char buffer[SOME_BIG_NUMBER];
    size_t buffercnt = 0;
    
    do {
       ssize_t num_read = read(pipe_fd, &c, 1);
       if (num_read == -1) {
           perror("Pipe read error");
           close(pipe_fd);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       buffer[buffercnt++] = c;
       assert(buffercnt < sizeof(buffer));
   } while (c != '\n');

Or you can read and write without newlines in the shell, like with echo -n or printf and read -n1.

echo "----logs being collected----" #; sleep 5
sleep 2
read -n1 -t1 new_value < "$pipe_name"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
STOP_FH_LOGS=$new_value
#if [ "$STOP_FH_LOGS" == "1" ]; then
echo "Updated STOP_FH_LOGS: $STOP_FH_LOGS"
else
echo "Empty Pipe!!"
fi

In this part of the code also, as u suggested I am using -n1 and -t1 both for reading from script without getting stuck, but the script is still stuck

So? I do not understand. Most probably it is getting "stuck" because there is nothing to read from the pipe. Should there be? Why / why not? Also, comments are very bad to paste code. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155570/209955  for help with debugging bash scripts.
